# Albert Finney, RIP

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Albert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Finney) [Finney](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001215/) (1936–2019)

[image: Albert Finney]

Although not especially known for his science fiction or fantasy work, Finney did play a cryogenically frozen head (of his character from the earlier fantastical serial *[Karaoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karaoke_(TV_series))*) in the 1996 British television serial *[Cold Lazarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_Lazarus)*.

[image: Cold Lazarus]

He was, in any event, an excellent actor.

Comment: He might be best known for his role as Daddy Warbucks in the 1982 musical *Annie*. RIP

Comment: So sad.  He was just perfect in Wolfen.  I feel sorry for anyone who knows that movie only from home video.  It has to be seen on the big screen to be appreciated -- I sat through two consecutive screenings and went back to see it three more times on its first run.  I think he played the definitive Ebenezer Scrooge in the Leslie Bricusse musical version of Scrooge, and was also my favorite Hercule Poirot in Murder on the Orient Express.  What a loss.

Answer (score 5):

He was good. He was a good actor.